# How to extract a float number from string using loop [python]

Tags: string, python-2.7, while-loop, floating-point, integer

I use this loop to extract integers, what changes should I make to this loop which will accept decimal numbers. 
Here inputn is a string:

```
def numberseeker():
global i, inputn, number, num
while i < len(inputn):
    if inputn[i].isalnum() is True:
        num = float(inputn[i])
        if inputn[i] == 0:
            number += num
        else:
            number = (number * 10) + num
        i += 1
    elif inputn[i].isalnum() is False:
        ope = inputn[i]
        operator(ope)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since inputn is a string, what's your meaning of this statement?
...
if inputn[i] == 0:
...

Because inputn[i] is a char, not an integer, so 
inputn[i] == 0
will always be false. Even this line doesn't make sense, your original codes still could work correctly. But it's still better to change it to only one line:
number = (number * 10) + num

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Done